# How do I create symbolic links using ruby in Windows 7

Tags: ruby, symlink

I need to create a symbolic link of a js file. 
I tried the below:

```
x = "C:/Program Files/apache-tomcat-7.0.41/webapps/analytics/js/analyticsController.js"
y = "c:/svn/web/src/main/webapp/analytics/js/analyticsController.js"
exec ("mklink #{x} #{y}")
```

and also `system ("mklink #{x} #{y}")`

neither of them created symbolic link. 
I was able to run commands like `system ("echo Hello") #prints hello` using ruby script

The mklink does not create the symbolic link. The console did not show any result either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [mklink command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx) on Windows (7 and above) requires a parameter for the type of link to make. Symbolic links on windows are the "shortcuts" that normal users can make themselves. What you likely are intending to create is a hard link, or "junction point". The command to create a junction point is:

`mklink /J <destination> <source>`

So, in ruby, this is:

<s>`exec ("mklink /J #{x} #{y}")`</s>

Apparently the cmd.exe shell only has access to mklink, so it has to be invoked first.

`exec ("cmd.exe /c \"mklink /J #{x} #{y}\"")`

One final note (of caution). Making links on Windows requires full administrator access.

Comment: Acutally, i typed in mklink "C:/Program Files/apache-tomcat-7.0.41/webapps/analytics/js/analyticsController.js" "c:/svn/web-framework/src/main/web/analytics/js/analyticsController.js" in the command prompt and it works fine, it created the symbolic link

Comment: I also tried. You are right, it does default to a symbolic link. It is possible mklink is not available outside of the cmd.exe interface, and you would need to open a cmd.exe shell, then execute mklink. `cmd.exe /c "mklink /J <dest> <source>"` should work.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby 2.3 supports symbolic links on Windows. You can use `File.symlink`.